# Visual Studio 13 cursor after parentheses

Tags: visual-studio-2013, parentheses

Is there a way to make visual studio put the cursor after parentheses?

What I mean is when I'm for example typing my function, who doesn't need any argument, I want VS to put the cursor after parentheses, not inside them.

Comment: It's very possible this can be done with a macro.

Comment: What do you mean by macro?